# How to transfer a custom domain name from expired/deleted susbscription to new Web App?

Tags: azure, ssl, dns

I maintain a family web site on Azure on my spare time. For a small fee, we have purchased a custom domain name to make it more "professional".

Unfortunately, the credit card associated with the susbscription has expired and since I was not actively monitoring the dedicated mail account I had created for this purpose, the susbscription has now been deleted (the susbscription is actually disabled in the portal, but the mail from Azure says that I need to create a new subscription if I want to change my mind).

In a matter of minutes, I registered a new subscription and thanks to continuous deployment, I could deploy the Web App from sources that I had kept on a GitHub account. However, an attempt to bring an external domain to the Web App fails with the reason being that the said domain is already in use by another Azure web site (presumably, the old Web App from the, now deleted, subscription)

A quick chat with the @AzureSupport team on Twitter, they suggested I file a support request from the Azure portal. However, since this is not a professionnal susbscription, I do not have a support plan. I see that support costs 25 $/month for at least 6 months in my situation.

This seems a bit too costly, like an order of magnitude higher than buying a new domain name for several years. At the same time, I don't understand why the deleted account is still locking the custom domain name. And it seems unfair that I need to pay to recover a domain name that I own but am unable to benefit from because it is associated with a Web App in a disabled Azure subscription!

Please, what are my options?

PS: Even though this is not a programmatic question, I post here because that's where Microsoft recommends to obtain community support. I have also posted a similar question on an appropriate MSDN Forum but the answers there are not satisfying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately on a technical level this will be something that can only be rectified by Azure support. Since you no longer have access to the account they will need to delete that domain association.

It is excessive that you are required to pay for a six month support contract to resolve an issue that is clearly an issue with the way Azure decommissions subscriptions.

The problem you now have is that you can't use Azure to host this domain until that association is removed. Your only options are to either have the complexity of using a VM or to move your site to AWS etc.

If you make those points to @AzureSupport team, *maybe* they will process it for you. Point them to this question and ask them to help you to keep using Azure.